# Imaginary Part of log(f(z))

Tags: complex-analysis

Let

$f(z)=z^2+4$

My question is, how the picture of

$M=\{z\in\mathbb C:\operatorname{Im}(\log(f(z)) > 0\}$ looks like.

My attempt is that 
$\operatorname{Im}(\log(f(z))=\arg(f(z))$
which let's me guess, that $\operatorname{Im}(f(z))$ and $\operatorname{Re}(f(z))$ both had to be greater than zero or smaller than zero, as $\arctan(x) > 0$, if $x>0$.
Can anyone help me with this issue?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What branch of the argument function are you using for Im(log(z))?

Comment: I forgot to say, that I am talking about the main branch of the log, meaning that the negative real axis is "cut out".

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:)** 
With $z=x+iy$ then
$${\bf Im}\,\log(z^2+4)=\arctan\dfrac{2xy}{x^2-y^2+4}>0$$
this concludes $xy(x^2-y^2+4)>0$. With this condition we can find the region which determine $z$ in the plane. This isn't a handsome shape and regard to $x$ and $y$ lies in or out of hyperbola $y^2-x^2=4$.

Comment: There's a small error in your $\arctan$ equation. The denominator should be $x^2-y^2+4$ rather than as shown.

Comment: @CyeWaldman Yea. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was my first thought aswell.
But isn't it easier?

Can't I just say that for the principal value of the log if $f(z)= re^{i\phi}$ that $Im (log(f(z)) = \phi > 0 $ when the imaginary part of $f(z)>0$ ?

Otherwhise I get a negative value for $\phi$ as the principal of the log is defined with $\phi \in ]-\pi,\pi[$  meaning that if the imaginary part of it's argument is less zero, that $\phi \in ]-\pi,0[$.

Can anybody tell me if I'm wrong? Thanks allready for the fast answer.